# ¿Cómo convertir una imagen de color a blanco y negro en C#?

Tags: c#, imagen

He estado buscando una forma de convertir una imagen a blanco y negro, **NO en escala de grises** como [esto](https://josebgd.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/convertir-imagenes-a-escala-de-grises-c-3/) o este [otro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/communitydocs/net-dev/csharp/convertir-una-imagen-a-escala-de-grises), sino solo blanco y negro, pero lo unico que encuentro es convertirlo a escala de grises lo cual no es util para lo que necesito hacer, si alguien me ayuda se los agradeceria.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Bitmap BinaryImage(Bitmap source, int umb)
        {
            // Bitmap con la imagen binaria
            Bitmap target = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height, source.PixelFormat);
            // Recorrer pixel de la imagen
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int e = 0; e < source.Height; e++)
                {
                    // Color del pixel
                    Color col = source.GetPixel(i, e);
                    // Escala de grises
                    byte gray = (byte)(col.R * 0.3f + col.G * 0.59f + col.B * 0.11f);
                    // Blanco o negro
                    byte value = 0;
                    if (gray > umb)
                    {
                        value = 255;
                    }
                    // Asginar nuevo color
                    Color newColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(value, value, value);
                    target.SetPixel(i, e, newColor);

                }
            }

            return target;
        }
```

Variando el valor del umb = umbral vas a tener el blanco y negro que necesitas recomendado umbral de 50 a 100